# Retrieving data from Arduino UNO via USB COM PORT

Tags: php, windows, arduino, serial-port

I am working on a project with Arduino UNO. My task is to receive data from the Arduino and save it to the database using PHP (first, I am trying to get data in php code, saving to database is quite easy).

I am using Windows operating system.
Using WAMP, php version: 5.5.12

The problem is: I cannot figure out how to properly read data via COM port.

Arduino sample code:

```
float temp;
int tempPin = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 temp = analogRead(tempPin);
 temp = temp * 0.48828125;
 Serial.print(temp);
}

void loop()
{

}
```

PHP code behind (arduino is using COM3):

```
<?php

   exec("MODE COM3: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1");

    $portAddress = 'COM3:';

    // Open connection on port
    $port = fopen($portAddress, 'rb+');

    stream_set_timeout($port, 0, 100);
  stream_set_blocking($port,0);

    // Necessary when the Arduino reset after the connection
    sleep(2);


    $msg = fread($port, 1);

    // Close connection
    fclose($port);

    echo $msg;
?>
```

the problem is that when I first run the php code, it looks like it is looping non stop and not opening the connection. If I try to refresh the page, I get 
[image]

I have tried looking up other questions on the forum but I could not find a similar situation. Could someone guide me to the solution of taking the value in php code?

Answer (score 1):

To start, I would add:

```
delay(1000);
Serial.write(temp);
```

To your main program loop in the Arduino sketch, why? - Without this, your program will just write the variable `temp` once and then do nothing forever, so add that to make testing easier.

Next, your PHP code. It seems like something simple, are you running the WAMP server with elevated permissions? PHP is trying to access COM in windows on the hardware level, you'll need elevated permissions. You're using `rb+` so transmission processing is disabled, it might prove to work through the different action types, because there are layers between PHP and the machine, like the WAMP server that could be tampering with the data. Your timing isn't going to work, the system isn't synchronous, the Arduino's transmission can't be anticipated without a handshake, you need to loop and wait until a transmission is received before processing it, which might wreak havoc with the WAMP server.

Comment: I will try it this evening and give you my results.

Comment: Wrote the code into the loop. Althou not Serial.write, but Serial.println. Ran wamp as administrator, but no luck. Still the same issue