# how to write serial data to phpmyadmin from arduino via usb port communication

Tags: php, arduino, phpmyadmin, xampp, serial-port

I am working on a project with Arduino UNO. My task is to receive data from the Arduino and save it to the database using PHP (first, I am trying to get data in php code, saving to database is quite easy).

I am using Windows operating system. Using WAMP, php version: 5.5.12

The problem is: I cannot figure out how to properly read data via COM port.

Arduino sample code:

```
float temp;
int tempPin = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 temp =        analogRead(tempPin);
  temp = temp * 0.48828125;
  Serial.print(temp);
}

void loop()
{

}
```

PHP code behind (arduino is using COM3):

```
<?php

    exec("MODE COM3:      BAUD=9600 PARITY=N DATA=8     STOP=1");

$portAddress = 'COM3:';

// Open connection on          port
    $port =      fopen($portAddress, 'rb+');

   stream_set_timeout($port, 0, 100);
```

stream_set_blocking($port,0);

```
// Necessary when the Arduino reset after the connection
sleep(2);


$msg = fread($port, 1);

// Close connection
fclose($port);

echo $msg;
?>
```

the problem is that when I first run the php code, it looks like it is looping non stop and not opening the connection. If I try to refresh the page, I get enter image description here

I have tried looking up other questions on the forum but I could not find a similar situation. Could someone guide me to the solution of taking the value in php code?
DISCLAIMER; This is a rePOSTED question by Deividas.Any vital answer pliz

Comment: Why are you re-posting someone's post that was posted [5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35393622/4902099)? and using the code that obviously not working?

Comment: @hcheung. Its obviously because you did not answer deividas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving data from Arduino UNO via USB COM PORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393622/retrieving-data-from-arduino-uno-via-usb-com-port)

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP part, please use **dio_open** for starting the connection, then use **dio_read**

For the case of `com3` (assuming is `9600 8-N-1`) :

```
<?php

exec('mode com3: baud=9600 data=8 stop=1 parity=n xon=on');

$fd = dio_open('com3:', O_RDWR);

while (1) {

  $data = dio_read($fd, 256);

  if ($data) {
     echo $data;
  }
}

?>
```

Amend the above codes to suit your further needs. (you may use a variable (or say query a data from a server db table) to replace the `1` in the while (1) to control when to stop reading data, but killing the php effectively stops it)